# I am trying to clean my downloaded images to detect only those images in which >=2 eyes are detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, classification, face-detection

```
def detect_2_eyes(img_path):
    #print(img_path)
    img_1=cv2.imread(img_path)
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    for x,y,w,h in faces:
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img_1[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        if len(eyes)>=2:
            return roi_color
```

#Will return only images where 2 eyes are detected

#To check my code  I'm just trying my hands on whether my iteration is ok/not

```
path_to_main_dir='C:/Users/USER/Projects/OpenCV/Celebrity Classification/image dataset'
path_to_cr_dir='C:/Users/USER/Projects/OpenCV/Celebrity Classification/image dataset/cropped'

import os
image_dir=[]
for entry in os.scandir(path_to_main_dir):
    if entry.is_dir():
        image_dir.append(entry.path)
print(image_dir)

c=1
celebrity_name = image_dir[0].split('\\')[-1]
for i in os.scandir(image_dir[0]):
    roi_color = detect_2_eyes(i.path)
    if roi_color is not None:
        print(c)
        plt.imshow(roi_color)
        c+=1
```

#I am having c 1-16 but only 1 image is being shown, and when I use cv2.write,it's only selecting this image only. Full code is here.

```
cropped_image_dirs = []
celebrity_file_names_dict = {}

for img_dir in image_dir:
    count = 1
    celebrity_name = img_dir.split('/')[-1]
    print(celebrity_name)

celebrity_file_names_dict[celebrity_name] = []

for entry in os.scandir(img_dir):
    roi_color = detect_2_eyes(entry.path)
    if roi_color is not None:
        
        cropped_folder = path_to_cr_dir + celebrity_name
        if not os.path.exists(cropped_folder):
            os.makedirs(cropped_folder)
            cropped_image_dirs.append(cropped_folder)
            print("Generating cropped images in folder: ",cropped_folder)
            
        cropped_file_name = celebrity_name + str(count) + ".png"
        cropped_file_path = cropped_folder + "/" + cropped_file_name 
        
        cv2.imwrite(cropped_file_path, roi_color)
        celebrity_file_names_dict[celebrity_name].append(cropped_file_path)
        print(count)
        count += 1
```

Comment: What is the problem / issue you're facing, please?

Comment: Post and example image to some free hosting service and put the URL in a comment or your post.

Comment: @JovialJoeJayarson I have 5 folders containing 5 different persons' images(downloaded raw image). I want to filter out only those pictures where 2 eyes has been detected using opencv. Then want to create a 'cropped' folder where only the detected images will be stored with their respective names say - directory 'messi_cropped_images' contains all the detected images with names messi_01.png,messi_02.png like this.   
cropped/messi_cropped_images/messi_01..., cropped/ronaldo_cropped_images/ronaldo_01

Comment: @RahulDey I understand. But my question is, where does the code go wrong? What erroneous results does it produce?

Comment: @JovialJoeJayarson It is only creating a single folder inside 'cropped', and inside that only one image. But I've checked there are 18 images with 2 eyes detected. Could you pls suggest me how do I proceed in order to do this, is my approach right?